# Unable to add a convenience initialiser to an SKShapeNode subclass

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, initialization, subclass, skshapenode

Trying to add a `convenience init` to an `SKShapeNode` subclass generates two compiler errors:

```
class Shape : SKShapeNode {
    convenience init(diameter: CGFloat) {
        self.init(circleOfRadius: diameter / 2) // error: Use of 'self' in delegating initializer before self.init is called
    } // error: Self.init isn't called on all paths in delegating initializer
}
```

Yet, if you paste the following code into a playground, it compiles and executes as expected:

```
import CoreGraphics
import SpriteKit

class FakeShapeNode : SKNode {
    convenience init(circleOfRadius radius: CGFloat) {
        self.init()
    }
}

class FakeShape : FakeShapeNode {
    convenience init(diameter: CGFloat) {
        self.init(circleOfRadius: diameter / 2)
    }
}

let shape = FakeShape(diameter: 3)
```

The question is, what could be the relevant difference here between `FakeShapeNode` and `SKShapeNode`?

**Edit**

As suggested by @Knight0fDragon, below a reminder of the relevant initialisation rules may be helpful:

> Assuming that you provide default values for any new properties you
>   introduce in a subclass, the following two rules apply:
>
> **Rule 1** If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass
>   designated initializers.
>
> **Rule 2** If your subclass provides an implementation of all of its superclass designated initializers—either by inheriting them as per
>   rule 1, or by providing a custom implementation as part of its
>   definition—then it automatically inherits all of the superclass
>   convenience initializers.
>
> These rules apply even if your subclass adds further convenience initializers.

Comment: Are those your entire subclass implementations? In the first example, it looks like you have an instance variable that's being set before the superclass's initializer is called.

Comment: The classes `Shape` and `FakeShape` are meant to be exactly analogous. These are not extensions so there is nothing out of view – i.e. in terms of instance variables, there aren't any. Of course, there may be (and are) inherited instance variables, but in both cases, the new convenience initialiser is delegating to a superclass convenience initialiser so this should not be a relevant difference (else this is a compiler bug).

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a convenience init call the super's convenience init,  it has to be a delegating initializer. Unfortunately there is a bug in playgrounds that will allow it to work, but in applications, you will receive the error you are seeing.

To understand how convenience inits work, please see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Initialization.html

Comment: no, I mean playgrounds will allow it when it should not be allowing it,  I changed my answer a little bit to clarify.

Comment: But, the second snippet does compile within an app project... as it should given the rules of initialisation.

Comment: (notice that the two initialisers in question delegate to `self.init...`)

Comment: yeah, look at that,  I can't explain that,  The rule of thumb is convenience inits  delegate across and  designated inits delegate up, so maybe something is going on with custom subclassing that is not going on with the built in libraries, thus forcing you to delegate up

Comment: Notice the last line of the rules I just added to the question. The `super`'s convenience initialisers should be available to me as my own here.

Comment: yeah, it is definitely not inheriting correctly,  perhaps the bug is on the app side and not playgrounds,  when you do super.init,  all of the convenience initializers are available, but if you self.  none are.

Comment: A work around you could do is to do an extension: extension SKShapeNode
{
    convenience init(diameter: CGFloat) {
        self.init(circleOfRadius: diameter / 2)
    }
}: but you can't override this either in a sub class

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Knight0fDragon. Let me just clarify that the question is not about a workaround but the reason for the discrepancy. The second snippet demonstrates expected behaviour, and indeed it compiles everywhere. The problem is why is the same not true when subclassing from `SKShapeNode` – the most probable reason being the C++ implementation details of `SpriteKit` classes...